# Rails3 validation okay in console fails in test_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, testing, helper

My validation contains a pluck(:id) statement. The validation works in console but fails in test_helper. If I replace that function with the array the function would return, all tests pass in console and in test_helper.

Here are the details:

I run Rails 3.2.13 on Kubuntu 12.04.

Set up two models in a virgin project:

> user - rails g model user role_id:integer
>
> role - rails g model role role_name:string

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :role_id

 #validates :role_id, inclusion: { in: [1, 2, 3] }  # validation using the result array.
 validates :role_id, inclusion: { in: Role.pluck(:id) }  # validation using the pluck(:id) function.

end
```

app/models/role.rb is as generated.

Added three Roles using the console. id's are [1, 2, 3].

Checked validation in console.

```
u = User.new(role_id: 1)
u.valid?
=> true
u.role_id = 5 # value out-of-range
u.valid?
=> false
u.role_id = 2 # value in range
u.valid?
=> true
```

So, this validation seems to work as intended.

```
u.save
```

worked, too.

Then, added a test:

test/unit/user_test.rb

```
require 'test-helper'
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
 test "role_id must be valid" do
   @u = User.new(role_id: 1)
   assert(@u.valid?,"Invalid role")
 end
end
```

Ran test with

```
rake test
```

Test failed, although role_id is correct as confirmed by console result.

If I replace the validation in app/models/user.rb with the commented one above

```
validates :role_id, inclusion: { in: [1, 2, 3] }
```

and comment out the other validation, test passes and console passes. Same effect with rspec. I repeated this several times now, always the same effect. Found a lot of interesting stuff on this site and played around with proc, lambda, blocks, custom validations, no success.

I guess I learned a lot, but start getting frustrated now. Could anybody direct me to my mistake(s)?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tests run in a different environment and DB (the test environment/DB, not coincidentally).

You need to have some test data, like roles.

There are multiple options including things like [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl), DB seeding, etc.

You can create the same failure in the console by starting in the test enironment:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails c
```

Comment: Dave, thank you very much. This helps a lot. I leanred something I will not forget. Fiddled around in RAILS_ENV=test rails c, and (certainly) confirmed what you wrote. Inserted roles in the test console environment. It worked once, but not a second time. I have to research more on the options you mentioned.

Comment: And- by the way, tried to push up the rating for your answer. Unfortunately not enough "reputation" yet. You helped somebody who made his first post ever. Working to improve both, reputation and rails skills. Great and helping hint, thanks again...

Comment: @user2498696 IIRC the test DB is cleaned out every time you run the tests so you start with completely-known data, although that may depend on how you're putting data into it. Accepting answers is the canonical way to indicate correctness/most helpful, upvoting requires some rep I think.

Comment: Slept a night, started refreshed and still being stuck, unfortunately. The test db is now populated with data [1,2,3] using the "dirty" fixtures way, validation works in test environment. Wrote a method in class User to print the content of the roles table -> puts "Role testdata: #{Role.pluck(:id)}". Used this print method in the test -> output was [1,2,3] when test ran, so test should use these data. Still, @u is always invalid if the User- validation is built with this pluck- statement, but passes when User- validation is built with the array [1,2,3].

Comment: @user2498696 The only way I can get this to fail is if the role was added *after* system startup. Recall that class declarations are just code: the `Role.pluck(:id)` is evaluated only when the `User` class is loaded; if you want it to reflect *changes* to the `Role` table then it *will* need to involve a function/lambda/proc/etc that is executed *at the time of validation*. Other than that, the code works as-is, with the pluck.

Comment: I think I  got it now. There is still almost too much to learn. Thanks a lot for your patience, very much appreciated. Hubert

Comment: @user2498696 It's a process--one step at a time. I recommend keeping a "development journal" of some sort, either via paper (my preference; I like the act of writing--but I copy it to a personal wiki) or whatever. Also consider keeping track of gained knowledge via code repositories, like on Github.